# AutoHotKey - Tool to suggest keystroke remappings?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey, and would like to remap keystrokes globally. I've got some going fine, but don't seem to be able to figure out how to do remappings with the Windows (or Super) key in some situations.

For example,

**How can I remap Shift+WinKey+F => Ctrl+Shift+F?**

I tried some stuff, but AutoHotKey complains about invalid mappings whenever I try to do so.

Here are my attempts so far:

```
#+F::^+F
Lwin & Shift & F::^+F
#+F::Send ^+F
```

What I'd like to find is a tool that figured out the mappings for me...

**Are there any tools out there that let me:**

- type an input keystroke, then
- type another keystroke,
- then the tool shows me the AutoHotKey mapping I'd need to use to map
  keystroke a to keystroke b?

I've seen various macro recorders, but they don't seem to focus on the remapping, just recording what I'm doing.

PS: I don't know if it would matter or not, but I'm using a Mac keyboard, and running Windows in a full screen virtual machine on a Mac ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about any tool that will do all that for you.  Most of what you want to do can in all likelihood be achieved programmatically.  Give the following a try:

```
#+f::Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}f{Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}
```